# Why FCM for Flutter does not allow subscribing to multiple topics at once? (Like a batch post endpoint)

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am curious to understand why this isn't possible?
The use case is that when logging in or out of the application, the user should subscribe/unsubscribe to multiple topics.

The only available option there is using the FCM library is

```
Foreach topic in topicList
   FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topic)
```

Is there something I'm missing or is this not the advised way to manage the topic subscriptions on the client side?